# ARM Assembly - Reading ".dat" extension / importing information

Tags: arm

I am supposed to create a program with the ".dat" extension, but ARMSim# doesn't read the file. First off, how am I supposed to have it read my file?

Also, the program I am writing needs to let the user input a list of numbers and the output should be the first integer, second integer, total number of integers, total numbers that are not the first integer, and total numbers that are not the second integer.

On top of it, it needs to check for errors and have a readable output.

I am completely stuck and obviously don't know any ARM. I would like to learn it since I will be having future projects that I hopefully will be able to do on my own, so if you can describe any code that would be great. The whole week I have been trying to read websites on ARM and I still stare blankly at the screen when I try to code anything. Any help would be GREAT.

Comment: Maybe you should team up with [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32799385/3156750) :P Break the problem down: you have 3 things to get your head around in order to write a working program - the general concept of programming in assembly (registers, memory addressing, how to implement variables, etc.); the environment provided by ARMSim# (how does it deal with files, what kind of I/O operations does it provide); and the ARM instruction set itself. In that order of importance, IMO.

Comment: Additionally, "help, I have no idea how to get started on my assignment" is not really a ["professional or enthusiast"](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) programming question, it's one to address first and foremost to your teachers (or whoever set you the assignment). Once you've got some code written, and you can't for the life of you figure out why it doesn't seem to behave the way the documentation leads you to you expect, _then_ you've probably got the makings of a question to post here.